# How to iteratively take specific struct elements and store them into a 2D array in C?

Tags: c, string, struct, dijkstra, adjacency-matrix

So I have a 2D array of strings, like this:

```
char str[12][100] = {
    "a = 2.b, 1.d",
    "b = 2.a, 1.e, 2.c",
    "c = 2.b, 1.f",
    "d = 1.a, 1.g",
    "e = 1.h, 1.b",
    "f = 1.i, 1.c",
    "g = 1.j, 1.d",
    "h = 1.k, 1.e",
    "i = 1.l, 1.f",
    "j = 1.g, 2.k",
    "k = 2.j, 1.h, 2.l",
    "l = 2.k, 1.i"
};
```

These strings represent a map layout, where point "a" is connected to point "b" and "d" and there is an associated distance (or weight) between the points that are connected to point "a". Here is what the layout looks like when converted from all those strings:

```
    a--(2)--b--(2)--c
    |       |       |
   (1)     (1)     (1)
    |       |       |
    d       e       f
    |       |       |
   (1)     (1)     (1)
    |       |       |
    g       h       i
    |       |       |
   (1)     (1)     (1)
    |       |       |
    j--(2)--k--(2)--l
```

And I have a struct, like this:

```
struct stopPoints {
    int  weights[10];
    char connectingPoints[10];
};
```

I've successfully taken each string, and put each letter and number into its own struct. I did that by creating an array of structs like this: `struct stopPoints store[26];`and then i proceeded to fill each struct iteratively by adding the appropriate element of each string. For example, for my first string `"a = 2.b, 1.d"` , I put the letters "a" "b" and "d" into `store[0].connectingPoints[0], store[0].connectingPoints[1], and store[0].connectingPoints[2],` respectively. So like this:

```
store[0].connectingPoints[0] = 'a';
store[0].connectingPoints[1] = 'b';
store[0].connectingPoints[2] = 'd';
```

I also put in the two numbers into the "weights" element of the struct, like this:

```
store[0].weights[0] = 2;
store[0].weights[1] = 1;
```

I've tested this out for all 12 strings and everything is in place.

Now, I want to create an adjacency matrix out of these strings that I have. Here is what the adjacency matrix should look like:

```
0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                        
2 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                        
0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0                                        
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0                                        
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0                                        
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0                                        
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0                                        
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0                                        
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 2                                        
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0
```

To explain a bit more, the first row [0] (represents point "a") contains 2 in the [0][1] index (representing the distance to point "b") and contains 1 in the [0][3] index (representing the distance to point "d").

As such, the second row [1] contains a 2 in the [1][0] and [1][2] index because point b is connected to point a and point c and index [1][5] contains a 1 because point b is also connected to point e. As you can see, each row and column actually represent the letters a-l in order (0=a, 1=b, 2=c, etc).

I've already initialized and populated a 12x12 array with all 0's. I just can't seem to properly populate my weight values to the corresponding index. Here is one of my many failed approaches:

```
int row2, col2, ugh=1;        
for (row2 = 0; row2 < 12; row2++){
    for (col2 = 0; col2 < 12; col2++){
        while(store[row2].connectingPoints[ugh] != NULL){
            adjmatrix[row2][col2] = store[row2].weights[col2];
            ugh++;
        }
}
```

}

Here is how you would hardcode the first two strings into the adjacency matrix:

```
        //a=2b, 1d;
        adjmatrix[0][0] = 0; //point a
        adjmatrix[0][1] = store[0].weights[0];
        adjmatrix[0][3] = store[0].weights[1];

        //b=2a, 2c, 1e;
        adjmatrix[1][0] = store[1].weights[0];
        adjmatrix[1][1] = 0; //point b
        adjmatrix[1][2] = store[1].weights[1];
        adjmatrix[1][4] = store[1].weights[2];
```

I just don't know how I can do this iteratively. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Detail: `char str[12][100]` is not a 2D array of _strings_.  It could be  called a 1D array of _strings_ or a 2D array of `char`.

Comment: @chux thanks for the clarification, that always confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting from the `char[][]` to `adjmatrix` can be done with some string parsing as done in the code below.

```
int adjmatrix[26][26] = {0}; //assuming 26 possible points (from question "struct stopPoints store[26]")

int i,j,k = 0;
int n = 12;

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int l = strlen(str[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < l; ++j) {
        if (str[i][j] == '.') {
            adjmatrix[str[i][0] - 'a'][str[i][j+1] - 'a'] = getWeight(str[i], j);
            // (char) - 'a', gives an integer value for the small case alphabets (a->1, b->2, c->3 ...)
        }
    }
}
```

`getWeight()`

```
int getWeight(char s[], int j) {
    // returns the integer on left of '.' from the string
    int w = 0,i = 0;
    int m = 1;
    for (i = j-1; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; --i) {
        w += (s[i] - '0')*m;
        m *= 10;
    }
    return w;
}
```

If you really need to use the struct then you can probably make it easier by making the number of `weights` equal to the number of `connectingPoints` for each store. i.e., if you are adding `store[0].connectingPoints[0] = 'a';` let the weights be

```
store[0].weights[0] = 0;  // weight of point a to point a
store[0].weights[1] = 2;  // weight of point a to point b
store[0].weights[2] = 1;  // weight of point a to point d
```

Another e.g.: `"c = 2.b, 1.f",` (Not sure what the order of `connectingPoints` in your code is, but notice the one to one mapping of points and weights based on index)

```
store[2].connectingPoints[0] = 'b';
store[2].connectingPoints[1] = 'c';
store[2].connectingPoints[2] = 'f';

store[2].weights[0] = 2;
store[2].weights[1] = 0;
store[2].weights[2] = 1;
```

If you know that there are no self-loops, you can avoid storing them in `connectedPoints` and further adding a respective entry to `weights`.

In that case, you can build the `adjmatrix` using a loop like this

```
struct stopPoints store[26];

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int l = strlen(store[i].connectingPoints);
    for (j = 0; j < l; ++j) {
        adjmatrix[str[i][0] - 'a'][store[i].connectingPoints[j] - 'a'] = store[i].weights[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! So I do need to use structs so I can't change that unfortunately, it comes into play during a different part of my project. I tried building the adjmatrix like you showed but it is still not producing the right output. I think its because my number of weights and number of coordinate points aren't the same. I'm having some difficulties changing that but is there a way around that? I'd like to keep my weights starting from index 0 and onward.

Comment: Actually, I was able to change that. I now have it where my weights and connecting points all line up. So my store[0].weights[0] is now 0 for all of them. But it is still producing the wrong output....

Comment: @missmouse314 made some edits to the answer. Think it is more clear now. Add weights[i] = 0 only for the self loop edges. E.g. if `store = 'c'` and `c.connectingPoint = 'c'`. If you think there are no self loops in your data, you can avoid adding them to `connectingPoints` in the first place.

Comment: My apologies, that is what I meant. For the self loop edges, i've made their weights 0. But it is still not producing the correct output using the code that you provided using the structs. I understand the logic, but I'm still getting 0's in places where it should be a 1 or a 2

Comment: @missmouse314 sorry it was my mistake. You need to update with indices `adjmatrix[str[i][0] - 'a'][store[i].connectingPoints[j] - 'a']`. Missed the `-'a'` part in the previous update.

Comment: thanks a lot! There was also one additional thing I missed that helped me figure it out. I got most of the adjacency matrix right, but I now have a new problem. For my point "b", notice how I have 3 points that b is connected to. For my next iteration (so when i move on to point "c"), the third connecting point gets transferred over to the rest of the points after "b", until the loop hits the next point with three connected points (point "k"). How would I fix that? I know I have to clear it somehow so it doesn't carry over....I just don't know how.

Comment: I was able to solve everything! thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Character to Integer Conversion**

You can find a copy of the ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/). You should bookmark this page, because if you spend much time programming, you'll refer to it a fair amount (twice a year, say, for 30+ years).

The important thing to know about the ASCII code (which is a subset of Latin1, Unicode, etc.) is that the digits, and the upper case letters, and the lower case letters, are in three contiguous groups, in ascending order.

That is, the code for '0' is one less than the code for '1', etc., up to '9'. And the same is true for 'A'..'Z' and 'a'..'z'.

So you can convert your character values to an index value by simple subtraction:

```
int ch0 = 'a' - 'a';  // == 0
int ch1 = 'b' - 'a';  // == 1
int ch4 = 'e' - 'a';  // == 4
```

If you have a (lowercase, ASCII) character value, and subtract 'a' from it, you'll get an integer value in the range 0..25.

This means you can use that formula to compute both index values for your adjacency matrix:

```
#define MAX_CONN 10
#define NUM_STORES 12
#define STORE_INDEX(ch) ((ch) - 'a')
#define FIRST_STORE 'a'
#define END_STORES (FIRST_STORE + NUM_STORES)
#define MAX_WEIGHT 100

// NOTE: I'm ignoring return type, and adjmatrix's 
// lifetime, in favor of just putting this code all 
// in one place. You'll have to figure out the rest.

void build_adj() {

    struct stopPoints store[NUM_STORES]; // Values?
    int adjmatrix[NUM_STORES][NUM_STORES] = {0};

    for (st = FIRST_STORE; st < END_STORES; ++st) {
        int row = STORE_INDEX(st);

        // Set default weights: MAX_WEIGHT or 0 (for self)

        for (i = 0; i < NUM_STORES; ++i) {
                adjmatrix[row][i] = MAX_WEIGHT;
        }

        adjmatrix[row][row] = 0;

        // Install parsed weights for this row

        for (iconn = 0; iconn < MAX_CONN; ++iconn) {

            // NB: setting connectingPoints[x] to '\0' invalidates connection.
            char st2 = store[row].connectingPoints[iconn];

            if (st2 != '\0') {
                adjmatrix[row][STORE_INDEX(st2)] = store[row].weights[iconn];

                // FIXME: Maybe set reflexive weight? a->b, b->a?
           }                                        
        }
    }
}
```

**Struct/Array Inversion**

Right now you have an array of struct that contains a pair of arrays. I'd suggest that you invert that, and build an array of struct holding a single array that contains a struct with two data elements.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct Connection {
    char  conn_target; 
    int   conn_weight;
} Connection;

typedef struct StopPoints {
    Connection sp_connections[MAX_CONN];
} StopPoints;
```

And then you have:

```
StopPoints store[MAX_STORES];

// most code stays the same

    st2 = store[row].sp_connections[iconn].conn_target;

// ...

    adjmatrix[row][STORE_INDEX(st2)] = store[row].sp_connections[iconn].conn_weight;
```

The advantage of this is conceptual: the connection target and weight are bundled together in the same struct. It makes this easier to think about, and easier to convert to using pointers ;-).

On the other hand, it will take more memory due to structure padding. But I don't think you care about that right now.